# Issue with XSLT line-break

Tags: html, xml, xslt

I'm having a problem. How can I instruct my XSLT to insert a new line?

Here's an example of my XML:

```
<message>Hello World!!! \r\n How You Guys Doing?!?</message>
```

or:

```
<message>Hello World!!! <br /> How You Guys Doing?!?</message>
```

and here's the XSL:

```
<html><body><xsl:valeof select="message"/></body></html>
```

Comment: What kind of line break do you want to output? An HTML one? Windows style? Something else? Which of the two XML examples is the one you want to transform? Both of them?

Comment: Additionally, your XSL is incorrect - is should be `xsl:value-of`, not `xsl:valueof`.

Comment: @HashCoder, when editing *Questions* we don't fix errors in code. Even in Answers, it's delicate...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming the input

```
<message>Hello World!!! <br /> How You Guys Doing?!?</message>
```

it should suffice to use

```
<xsl:copy-of select="message/node()"/>
```

in your XSLT. Replacing \r\n is more difficult, at least in XSLT 1.0. See http://www.dpawson.co.uk/xsl/sect2/N7240.html#d10122e406 for a possible approach.